# UINavigationBar disappears after UIImagePickerController is popped

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UIViewController that is embedded in a UITabBarController. On my `PhotoViewController` the user can select to add a photo and the `UIImagePickerController` is called. After the user selects the photo and the view is popped, the Navigation Bar disappears.

The Navigation bar is shown.

[image: Start]

This is the `UIImagePickerController` view, It looks as if the CANCEL button is under the `NavigationBar`. (It is hard to see in this picture.)

[image]

After the `UIImagePickerController` is popped and the view is reloaded, the `NavigationBar` is gone.

[image]

Here is how I call the `UIImagePickerController`. I am inheriting from `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

[image]

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Though the delegate is saying is it incompatible.

[image]
[image]

How do I correct issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
imagePickerController.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

And that seemed to put the imagePickerController on top of the current view.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of searching I didn't find proper solution. Problem was that I'm making navigation bar hidden in view which presents image picker, but when I Do:

```
imagePicker.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

before showing `present()` problem still appears, but when I do it every time after `dismiss()`, it works properly... like this:

```
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true)
imagePicker.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

I don't know why it works this way, but may be it helps someone. Please, explain this if some has answer.